# How to build Qt5.6 with QtWebKit on Mac OSX (El Capitan)

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qt5.6

I can't find any concrete pointers on the qt.io site how to actually build qt5.6 together with qtwebkit, so any hint is appreciated.
I can build qt5.6.0 flawlessly from the git repo in dev mode, however I don't know the further steps to re add qtwebkit.
Somebody out there who did it already?

Comment: It was ripped out, don't expect readding it to be easy. If you need QtWebKit, stick with 5.5. But migrate to the new stuff (what was it called, WebCore? WebView?)

Comment: https://github.com/qtproject/qtwebkit

Comment: @rubenv the new stuff is called qt webengine. We know about the existence but are unable to jump instantly to this latest and greatest tarball (hence the question) Our desire for 5.6 is official Metro WinRT appstore support

Answer (score 1):

I'm also trying to build Qt webkit together with 5.6.0, I got the source not from git but from the community release directory: http://download.qt.io/community_releases/5.6/5.6.0/

I put the content of the .tar.gz in qtwebkit submodule next to qtbase, it's trying to build it but then I have an error:

```
.pch/debug/QtWebKitWidgets_debug/c++.pch
../include/QtWebKitWidgets/QtWebKitWidgetsDepends:7:10: fatal error:               'QtWebKit/QtWebKit' file not found
#include <QtWebKit/QtWebKit>
     ^
1 error generated.
make[4]: *** [.pch/debug/QtWebKitWidgets_debug/c++.pch] Error 1
make[3]: *** [debug-all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-widgetsapi-pri-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-Source-QtWebKit-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make: *** [module-qtwebkit-make_first] Error 2
```

Comment: I fixed my issue, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117826/building-qtwebkit-with-qt-5-6-on-mac-10-11/36120205#36120205 if it can help

Answer (score 0):

`QWebKit` is deprecated as of 5.6.0 (https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.6) however it is still buildable for Qt 5.6 (but you should consider migrating at some point).

The easiest way to do it is to clone the `git` repository into the same source directory and build it like a normal `Qt` project. If you want to do it the ultra standard way you can add it as a submodule and follow the same steps they perform in the `init-repository` script but it's not necessary.

Comment: @Nicolas Smith So how does the top ./configure script know an option which is no more there by default? Just by presence in the subdir ? (I know that qtwebkit is deprecated , but we cannot switch instantly...its appears for us as "hey, we broke your code , but if you don't mind write your own QNetworkAccessManager replacement http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html#qt-webengine-does-not-interact-with-qnetworkaccessmanager and be aware that your app is some MB bigger")

Comment: @Leo I might be missing the point, but your link says literally that all functionality of `QNetworkAccessManager` was moved into `QWebEnginePage`. If you want the smallest possible app size, I suggest building Qt statically and performing strong link-time optimization to remove unused code from the final executable.