# Building QtWebKit with QT 5.6 on Mac 10.11

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qtwebkit, qt5.6

I'm trying to build Qt 5.6.0 (new release) with Qt Webkit on Mac OS 10.11 and I have a compiling error when I try.

I downloaded the tar.gz source of 5.6.0, then I downloaded QtWebkit source from Community folder for 5.6.0. I added the qtwebkit folder in the same folder of qtbase like previous version. Anything else is needed?

I'm using this configure:

```
OPENSSL_LIBS='-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto' ./configure -nomake examples -opensource -openssl-linked -I /usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

After a few hour of compilation, I have this error message:

```
.pch/debug/QtWebKitWidgets_debug/c++.pch
../include/QtWebKitWidgets/QtWebKitWidgetsDepends:7:10: fatal error:           'QtWebKit/QtWebKit' file not found
#include <QtWebKit/QtWebKit>
     ^
1 error generated.
make[4]: *** [.pch/debug/QtWebKitWidgets_debug/c++.pch] Error 1
make[3]: *** [debug-all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-widgetsapi-pri-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-Source-QtWebKit-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make: *** [module-qtwebkit-make_first] Error 2
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue while searching some mailing: http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2016-March/025358.html

The tarball was not properly made and the synqct step is missing.

To fix, create an empty .git folder (in qtwidget) and execute qmake, then manually execute syncqt for Qtwebkit:

```
cd qtwidget
mkdir .git
qmake
syncqt.pl Source -version 5.6.0
```